# How to turn jQuery $.get into Bluebird thenable?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, promise, bluebird

I want to `GET` with jQuery and thenable it's result but `then` is never happening; why? Of course I get my JSON response back. Below is full code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return $.get(url.address, url.options, 'json');
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Promise.resolve`, it converts a value or a `then`able from another library (like the return value of `$.get` into a Bluebird promise.

```
Promise.resolve($.get(...)) // converts to bluebird promise
```

Your example code is wrong - the promise constructor completely ignores return values - in the upcoming version of bluebird this is [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/an7qK.png).

Comment: It is not working for me, the following then always calls the fullfil handler when there is an error.

Comment: @WalterMacambira I answered your other question. For future readers: Walter had another issue - the code in this answer is fine.